# attach existing in-memory sqlite3 databases using python3

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite, in-memory-database

I have many sqlite3 databases (actual files) I wish to merge using a binary merge algorithm.
To do this, I use the python3 sqlite3 API to load them into memory (avoid I/O overhead) and start merging them in pairs (binary merge).
However, after creating, for instance, two in-memory databases:

```
conn_mem1 = connect('file:memdb1?mode=memory&cache=shared', uri=True)
conn_mem2 = connect('file:memdb2?mode=memory&cache=shared', uri=True)
```

How can I attach one to the other? I tried

```
cur_mem1 = conn_mem1.cursor()
cur_mem1.execute('ATTACH DATABASE 'file:memdb2?mode=memory&cache=shared' AS memdb2')
```

But that just seems to attach an empty database, and also creates an empty file with name

> memdb2?mode=memory&cache=shared

on disk in the current path.

How can I attach an existing in-memory database to another in-memory database?

Comment: Don't bother with that in-memory stuff; just attach the database files.

Comment: @Shawn are you sure that's a good idea if I have 100 files of about 0.1GB? (so 10GB total) Won't it get slow?

Comment: That's not a lot of data, but it's enough that it's definitely a good idea